# golang: How to get first bit of byte

Tags: go, bit-manipulation, byte, bitwise-operators, bit

I have a hash:

```
b := hash.Sum(nil)
```

I am really just interested in the first bit of that byte. Is it 0 or 1?

So far I have this:

```
s := strconv.FormatInt(int64(b[0]),2)
if s[0] == '0' {
 // it's 0
} else {
  // it's 1
}
```

But I am sure there is a much more elegant (and more performant?) way to do this.

Comment: Note that the code does not test a single bit.   The first byte of the FormatInt result is `’0’` for `b[0] == 0` only.

Comment: Thanks, I did a shortcut to my actual code and it came out horribly wrong. I'll edit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you could just check the result of bitwise and operator

```
if b[0] & 0x1 == 0x1 {
    // it's 1
} else {
    // it's 0
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Sum()` function of a hash returns a slice of bytes. You want to isolate the first bit of the first byte, correct?

It's a simple matter of bit-twiddling. 2 or 3 machine instructions at most.

Depending on what you mean by "first bit",

This gives you the high-order/most significant/leftmost bit of a byte:

```
func HighOrderBit(b byte) byte {
    return (b >> 7) & 0x01
}
```

And this gives you the low-order/least significant/rightmost bit of a byte:

```
func LowOrderBit(b byte) byte {
    return (b >> 0) & 0x01
}
```

Note that the above works for any integer type: the only difference being the size of the right shift in `highOrderBit()`. The number of bits to shift right is the size of the integer type in bits minus one (e.g., for a 64-bit integer, the shift value is 64-1, or 63).